# One tag per saint?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some would think it crazy, others pointless, but does anyone actually mind if I retag things like [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/why-was-thomas-more-canonized) with [st-thomas-more](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/st-thomas-more). [catholic-saints](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-saints) is probably too narrow and usually overlooks Orthodox, anglican saints etc... [saint](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saint) is way to broad and not very descriptive.

There are a finite number of existing saints, so it's not like 1 tag per video game on the arquade or one tag per author on the defunct lit.SE, so what do ya think?

Answer (score 7):

I think the limitation here is how many questions must be tagged something before the tag will survive. There is a garbage collection routine of sorts that removes tags that only appear in X (1?) questions.

I would say that for any Saint that has more than one question to their name, go for it, but leave some sort of broader tag for "saints" so that it is possible to find all these sorts of questions.

For any Saint that has only garnered one question, leave them with the generic tags until more than one comes along.

Comment: yes, as long as a tag is on 2+ questions it will stay forever, but it it's only on one it will age off after a period of time

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an issue with one tag/saint. The only concern I really have is that some of those tags may age away if they don't get more than one question each.

Comment: Oh, yet another feature I didn't know about, serves me right for not listening to the podcast since 2009.  I guess I won't bother unless there are more than one question to retag.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the `st-` prefix is rarely needed.  I know (in broad terms) which individual is being referred to by [thomas-more](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thomas-more), [aquinas](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquinas), [augustine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augustine), [francis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/francis), etc.  In cases where there might need to be disambiguation, other identifying text (such as the city they came from) seem more likely to help than their designation as a saint.

I agree with Caleb and wax that singleton tags are not useful, however.